# On the contrary

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrases, subordinate-clauses

> The man wasn't very trustworthy. On the contrary, he had been caught stealing twice from his boss.

The above sentence seems incorrect to me, as far as I know, the use of **on the contrary** is for denying/contradicting, but in this sentence both parts are giving the same negative thought about person. So the use of **on the contrary** doesn't seem to be fitting there. Any explanation is highly welcome.

Comment: I used to be puzzled by _On the contrary_ when I encountered it as a child. But it is indeed usually used not to contradict the previous statement, but to confirm or intensify the (negative) previous statement.

Answer (score 2):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*contrary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20contrary):

> **on the contrary**
>   : just the opposite
>   // The test will not be easy; *on the contrary*, it will be extremely difficult.

What the phrase does is contradict a claim *within* the previous clause:

> The test will not be **easy**.
> → The test will be *just the opposite of* **easy**.

---

The phrase doesn't contradict the *entire* previous sentence or clause, but only one simple fact *within* it:

> ✘ **The test will not be easy**. *On the contrary*, <sup>(of **the test not being easy**)</sup> it will be extremely difficult.
>
> ✔ The test will not be **easy**. *On the contrary*, <sup>(of **easy**)</sup> it will be extremely difficult.

---

So, in the example sentence in the question, it is contradicting **the trustworthiness** of the man:

> The man wasn't very **trustworthy**. *The man was just the opposite of* ***trustworthy*** [because] he had been caught stealing twice from his boss.
>
> The man wasn't very **trustworthy**. *On the contrary*, <sup>(of **trustworthy**)</sup> he had been caught stealing twice from his boss.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you: it doesn't seem like the best fit here. That's because I also interpreted 'on the contrary' to contrast the entire previous sentence, but I think it's only intended to contrast '(not) trustworthy'. However, it is correct.

Perhaps it's not the best structure by the author.
I would propose:

> The man wasn't very trustworthy. *In fact*, he had been caught stealing twice from his boss.

Or, if we are determined to keep 'on the contrary', we might change the adjective:

> The man was far from *honest*. On the contrary, he had been caught stealing twice from his boss.

Your understanding that 'on the contrary' is used for contradiction is perfectly correct.

Comment: I have to disagree that the phrase is used for contradition, as does the dictionary. You don't contradict yourself. The dictionary says it is for emphasis.

Comment: I wouldn't say you contradict yourself, no, but rather a term. Maybe contradiction is too strong, and denial of a previous statement is better. "Is he trustworthy? On the contrary, he's completely untrustworthy"

Answer (score -1):

It is correct. Remember, when you say "on the contrary", you're not contradicting *yourself*! So both your statements have to be true.

The phrase "on the contrary" is in the dictionary, and one definition is:

> used to intensify a denial of what has just been implied or stated by suggesting that the opposite is the case.

It is correct then that the second sentence would *agree* with the first, as it is being used to "intensify a denial". In your example, the first statement is a denial of his *trustworthiness*, and the second statement backs that up by demonstrating that, on the contrary, he has proved *untrustworthy*.